# Is it possible that the title "pharaoh " was applied to any Egyptian king before Thutmose III (c. 1479–1425 BCE)?

Tags: ancient-egypt

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharaoh):

> The word pharaoh ultimately derives from the Egyptian compound pr ꜥꜣ, */ˌpaɾuwˈʕaʀ/ "great house", written with the two biliteral hieroglyphs pr "house" and ꜥꜣ "column", here meaning "great" or "high". It was used only in larger phrases such as smr pr-ꜥꜣ "Courtier of the High House", with specific reference to the buildings of the court or palace. From the Twelfth Dynasty onward, the word appears in a wish formula "Great House, May it Live, Prosper, and be in Health", but again only with reference to the royal palace and not the person.
> Sometime during the era of the New Kingdom, Second Intermediate Period, pharaoh became the form of address for a person who was king. The earliest confirmed instance where pr ꜥꜣ is used specifically to address the ruler is in a letter to Akhenaten (reigned c. 1353–1336 BCE) that is addressed to "Great House, L, W, H, the Lord". However, there is a possibility that the title pr ꜥꜣ was applied to Thutmose III (c. 1479–1425 BCE), depending on whether an inscription on the Temple of Armant can be confirmed to refer to that king.*

My question:

Is it possible that the title "pharaoh " was applied to any Egyptian king before Thutmose III (c. 1479–1425 BCE)?

Are there any reasons to exclude the possibility that we may one day find an inscription of the title "Pharaoh " being applied to an Egyptian king before Thutmose ?

Comment: Proving negatives is hard.

Comment: Its *possible* a pot of water could boil without turning the heat on. However, its vanishingly unlikely.